# Ignore Permissions ExactTarget Abandon Checkout

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, permissions

Is it possible to ignore permissions via salesforce marketing cloud when it comes to a customer abandon checkout emails? ie if customer has unsubscribed but abandons checkout at a later date they still can receive abandon checkout emails?

Thanks

Comment: In your instance, does unsubscribe add them to a suppression list or do it update a value in a data extension?

Comment: It adds them to ExactTarget unsubscribe list

Comment: Transactional sends ignore subscriber status.  An order confirmation email would be considered transactional.  However, I don't believe an abandon cart would be considered transactional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the option to either honour or ignore a subscriber's status when sending transactional emails built into the system.

Under Admin / Send Management / Send Classifications, you can select from a Commercial or Transactional send type. The transactional option will both ensure the system doesn't check for the unsubscribe link, as well as let you send to subscribers who are unsubscribed in the Marketing Cloud.

[image]
By default this feature is unchecked, so you will likely already be sending to them if you are using a transactional send classification.

Most of the accounts we deal with treat Cart Abandonment emails as transactional, as they are using a 3rd party system to manage the card abandonment process. This 3rd party should have their own subscriber management system, which can be used on these types of emails. You want to make sure you are always letting users unsubscribe from emails unless they are 100% necessary.